# How can i add a GLSL Fragment Shader Audio Visualization

Tags: javascript, audio, glsl, webgl, visualization

How can i add Audio Visualization support to this class, i would like to add an Audio() object as an input to a GLSL Fragment Shader. An Example of this is https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mlj3WV. I know this sort of thing can be done in Canvas 2d with waveform Analysis, but this opengl method is far more smooth.

```
/* Code from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/webciter/GLSLFragmentShader/1.0.0/GLSLFragmentShader.js */

/* render function */

/* set the uniform variables for the shader */
 gl.uniform1f( currentProgram.uniformsCache[ 'time' ], parameters.time / 1000 );
gl.uniform2f( currentProgram.uniformsCache[ 'mouse' ], parameters.mouseX, parameters.mouseY );

/* i would like something like this */
gl.uniform2f( currentProgram.uniformsCache[ 'fft' ], waveformData );
```

The shader at ShaderToy Example accepts a float as fft, but this just updates the entire row of bars and not individual bar values. I would like real time manipulation of all bars.

Iv searched MDN but don't understand how to incorporate this, iv also looked at the source code of shadertoy.com but can't figure out how they have achieved this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadertoy does not provide FFT as a float. It provides FFT data as a texture

```js
"use strict";

window.addEventListener('click', start);  

function start() {
  window.removeEventListener('click', start);
  // make a Web Audio Context
  const context = new AudioContext();
  const analyser = context.createAnalyser();

  // Make a buffer to receive the audio data
  const numPoints = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  const audioDataArray = new Uint8Array(numPoints);
  
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = position;
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision mediump float;
  uniform vec2 resolution;
  uniform sampler2D audioData;
  void main() {
    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / resolution;
    float fft = texture2D(audioData, vec2(uv.x * 0.25, 0)).r;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(uv * pow(fft, 5.0), 0, 1);
  }
  `;

  const gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
  // compiles shaders, link program, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
  
  const tex = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
  gl.texImage2D(
     gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
     0,            // level
     gl.LUMINANCE, // internal format
     numPoints,    // width
     1,            // height
     0,            // border
     gl.LUMINANCE, // format
     gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // type
     null);  
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

  const arrays = {
    position: {
      numComponents: 2,
      data: [
        -1, -1,
         1, -1,
        -1,  1,
        -1,  1,
         1, -1,
         1,  1,
      ],
    }
  };
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  function render() {
    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // get the current audio data
    analyser.getByteFrequencyData(audioDataArray);

    // upload the audio data to the texture
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gl.texSubImage2D(
       gl.TEXTURE_2D, 
       0,            // level
       0,            // x
       0,            // y
       numPoints,    // width
       1,            // height
       gl.LUMINANCE, // format
       gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE,  // type
       audioDataArray);       

    // calls gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.bindBuffer, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
    // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniform
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      audioData: tex,
      resolution: [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height],
    });
    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  // Make a audio node
  const audio = new Audio();
  audio.loop = true;
  audio.autoplay = true;

  // this line is only needed if the music you are trying to play is on a
  // different server than the page trying to play it.
  // It asks the server for permission to use the music. If the server says "no"
  // then you will not be able to play the music
  // Note if you are using music from the same domain 
  // **YOU MUST REMOVE THIS LINE** or your server must give permission.
  audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

  // call `handleCanplay` when it music can be played
  audio.addEventListener('canplay', handleCanplay);
  audio.src = "https://twgljs.org/examples/sounds/DOCTOR%20VOX%20-%20Level%20Up.mp3";
  audio.load();


  function handleCanplay() {
    // connect the audio element to the analyser node and the analyser node
    // to the main Web Audio context
    const source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio);
    source.connect(analyser);
    analyser.connect(context.destination);
  }
}
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid black; display: block; }
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<div>click to start</div>
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl.min.js"></script>
```