# WebGL 3D -- Spectrogram functionality

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, html5-audio, webgl2

I am interested in learning WebGL 3D graphics and I stumbled upon this Github repo:

https://github.com/googlecreativelab/chrome-music-lab/tree/master/spectrogram

Demo: https://musiclab.chromeexperiments.com/Spectrogram/

I am a bit overwhelmed (and very impressed) on how this was setup.

Anyway, the question I have particularly is the mic functionality: based on the audio input that the browser it receives, I am trying to figure out how I can filter certain frequency range.

At the moment, it captures all types of frequency when using the mic. But what if I want to just show the highest/lowest frequency based on how it is receiving.

I spent hours trying to reverse engineer but had no luck.

If anyone can help me pinpoint where I should look at, that would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Visualizations_with_Web_Audio_API -- Check out the "Creating a frequency bar graph" section. getByteFrequencyData() spits out an array of frequency intensities. You can then use the bass / trebble bits for your visual.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57126857/128511